# OpenGL, freeGLut, and GLEW on Surface Pro

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, glew, freeglut

I am currently taking a college course in Computer Graphics and we are using Visual Studio 2012.

I am trying to get it set up to use freeGLUT and GLEW, but am currently not having any progress.

I have searched everywhere, but have not had any luck finding anything on using a Surface Pro to do this. My professor managed to get it to work on a desktop with Windows 8, but has not tried with a Surface Pro.

I currently do not have any other system to do this on or else I would use one, nor do I have the funds to purchase something else. The Surface Pro has been great for everything else so far, just not this.

*UPDATE*
I have had some better luck so far using GLEE and freeGLUT. I am now getting this error.

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\GL/gl.h(1157): error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'WINGDIAPI'

I included windows.h and now it is saying there are syntax errors in my gl.h

*UPDATE 2*
Program works now. the dll files are with the project files. I also had to reinstall Visual Studio 2012. Good news is IT WORKS! Thanks for those who showed interest and tried to help.

Comment: Are you getting errors? Can't download? Full disk drive?  Making no progress is way too generic.

Comment: When I build it, it says it the build is successful, but when I run it, it only says The program '[2816] 6E test.exe' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b). I have the latest versions of GLEW and freeGLUT downloaded, Visual Studio 2012 is installed, the freeGLUT libraries are copied into the system lib file, the .h files are copied into the include folder. I still have 50GB of disk space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like as always when it comes to OpenGL, Microsoft makes it not easy, because for some reason (we can only speculate about) they don't like OpenGL. Hence ever since Windows Vista they ship their products with no, or only limited OpenGL support.

The first step is, to go to [Intel.com and download the latest OpenGL drivers for the GPU the Surface Pro uses](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Laptop+graphics+drivers&ProductProduct=2nd+Generation+Intel%C2%AE+Core%E2%84%A2+Processors+with+Intel%C2%AE+HD+Graphics+3000%2f2000).

This should give you proper OpenGL support, though the Intel drivers for Windows are only mediocre.